# Rails 3.1 assets pipeline, how does it handle files with the same name? priority?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, asset-pipeline

This is problem, I'm using Typus, which includes a fancybox jquery plugin under /vendor/assets. That fancybox version is too old (1.3.4) and it does not work with rails 1.9.x so I need to replace that with fancybox 2.x that works with that version of jquery because the rest of my site uses jquery 1.9.

Typus's application.js manifest loads fancybox this way

```
//= require jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack
```

so I thought I could just add fancybox 2 with that file name and the asset pipeline would use that version instead but it's not, it's loading the file inside /vendor/assets.

So, my question is, how does rails handle that case when there's more than one file with the same name? is there any priority? and most important, can I change that so the files under /app/assets have more priority?

I've read it uses the first file it finds with the name but I don't know how to tell rails to look in some folder first.

I've tried

```
config.assets.paths = [Rails.root.join('app','assets')]
```

or

```
config.assets.paths = [Rails.root.join('app','assets'),Rails.root.join('vendor','assets')]
```

on my config/application.rb but it keeps using the file under /vendor/assets

I don't want to fork>modify Typus, I want to tell rails to use my jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js version of the file

I've seen on github that the last commit on Typus downgrades jquery to 1.8.x but I can't do that, I need jquery 1.9.

I'm also trying to override Typus's application.js inside my project but with no luck.